# Angularjs how to refer a local image in template html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load a local image as background image in CSS. My folder structure as below,

```
MyApp
    Public
        index.html
    html
        template.html
    images
        myimage.png
    javascripts
    stylesheet
```

Loading `index.html` from public folder and on click, loading `template.html` from html folder. In `template.html` i have defined the css like this,

```
textarea{
<!-- background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png); -->
background-image: url('../images/myimage.png');
background-attachment: local;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 35px;
padding-top: 10px;
border-color:white;
background-color: white; 
height:90%;
width:95%;
resize: none;
outline-width: 0;
}
```

And calling this in `template.html` as ,

```
<div id="bodydata" class="tabcontent" >
      <textarea rows="5" ng-model="description"></textarea>
</div>
```

It works beautifully when I take an image from web `"background-image: URL(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);"` but does not work when I change to the local image which is nothing but the same image downloaded and saved as the local copy.

```
background-image: url('../images/myimage.png');
```

I want to have it as local because the server may not have the internet connection. So how to refer the image in right way. I have tried many things like single quotes, double quotes, without quotes but it didn't work. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where your style sheet file located , is it under **stylesheet** folder ? or its inline style

Comment: it is inline style. put in template.html file itself in <style> tag. Nothing is from stylesheet folder.

Comment: Try to use `background-image: url('images/myimage.png')` , as i try it in **w3schools** try editor and the code is find. The problem on URL only

Comment: It didn't work. In fact i have put copies of myimage.png in all three folders, public, html and images and passed "background-image: url('myimage.png')" so it may take from somewhere but that also didn't work.

Comment: Try to use another browser ,because some browser cache the web pages when you access it for many time .Also can you share your component where you call template.html

Answer (score 0):

How is your web-server setup? Where is your web-server running from?

Depending on these answers, you should be able to achieve the desired result by adjusting your CSS like this:

```
background-image: url('/images/myimage.png');
```

So for instance, if your web-server is running in /MyApp, and is configured to allow static files to be fetched (eg files matching this pattern /images/*.png), then the answer above should work.

Comment: Yes @Dacre. My web-server is running in /MyApp. I have tried url('/images/myimage.png'); but didn't work

Comment: If you visit the url in your browser, do you see the image? 

So suppose your server is running on `localhost:8080`, are you able to see the image if you visit `localhost:8080/images/myimage.png` with your web browser?

Comment: Yes @Dacre. I am able to see image in my chrome browser when visit localhost:8080/images/myimage.png

Comment: Are you seeing and errors or warnings in devtools console? Can you verify that the css selector above is matching the <textarea> element (and can you also verify that the background-image rule is not being overridden by another rule elsewhere in your app)?

Comment: I dont see any error or waning in devtools. Please note, it is working when i use "background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);" so the chances of rule overridden are less.

Comment: Does it work if you supply an absolute url ? Eg http://localhost:8080/images/myimage.png

Comment: It doesn't work when i give like => background-image: url(http://localhost:8080/images/myimage.png);

Comment: Have you tried http in front of the url in your style sheet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169065/discussion-between-sand-and-dacre-denny).